# Report Logs In Cognos

Tags: cognos

Playing around in cognos Administration, I wasn’t able to see anywhere to export the Report Run Logs. Clicking on a successful Report, I’m able to see there were email recipients, but only the number of them, not who got the report:
so
is it possible to export the report logs in cognos?
 Does it include recipients?
Can we automate that log to be sent to others?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an Audit Store in Cognos configuration, and turn your logging levels up on your dispatcher in order to get detailed logs.